# How can I get multiple addresses using GoogleDistance in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use loop to get the distance and time for multiple addresses in Laravel

```
foreach ($driver as $product) {
    $googlePickupDistanceMatrix = new GoogleDistance(
        $product->current_latitude,
        $product->current_longitude,
        $sendLAT,
        $sendLNG,
    );

    $pickupDistanceAndTime2 = $googlePickupDistanceMatrix->distanceAndTime();
}
```

the $driver variable contains this

```
0 => App\Driver {#317 ▶}
1 => App\Driver {#300 ▶}
2 => App\Driver {#281 ▶}
```

The above code returns a single latitude and longitude for one address, I can't find the others, please help.

Comment: If you want multiple distances you will need to put them in an array rather than a scalar variable`$googlePickupDistanceMatrix[] = ....` Currently you are overwriting the previous distance with the next, until you get to the last, which is the only one you see

Comment: $driver is already an array

Comment: Yes but you are not storing the result of the `$googlePickupDistanceMatrix` into an array SO YOU SEE ONLY THE LAST

Comment: can u just pls rewrite the code to be sure ..cos am confused

Comment: the question format is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing the result of the distance request in a scalar varibale and hence overwriting all the results until you can only see that last one.

```
foreach ($driver as $product) {
    $googlePickupDistanceMatrix = new GoogleDistance(

        $product->current_latitude,
        $product->current_longitude,
        $sendLAT,
        $sendLNG,
    );

    $pickupDistanceAndTime2[] = $googlePickupDistanceMatrix->distanceAndTime();
// change                  ^^
}
```

If you get

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 15 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 15 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 29 ) 
)
```

they are the 3 array occurances holding the 3 results, so do another foreach

```
foreach ( $pickupDistanceAndTime2 as $dt ){
    echo 'Distance ' . $dt[0] . 'and Time ' . $dt[1] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Call to a member function distanceAndTime() on array

Comment: Woops my mistake, see change

Comment: I get the distance and time for only one driver.     0 => 4.0
1 => 15.0

Comment: it ought to be 3 drivers

Comment: After the foreach loop, do a `print_r($pickupDistanceAndTime2)`

Comment: ok now i get this Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 15 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 15 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 29 ) )

Comment: thank u, i think i am close to the answer..but not there yet